# Add an iterator number to a column after the first 8 results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column called Wosequence.  As of right now nothing is populated in that column when I query because nothing is technically in that column. What I am looking to do with my result set. Is to apply an iterator after the first 8 results. It will then populate wosequence with the result of the iterator. I do not need to insert data into the wosequence. I just need in my result set to have wosequence populated.

I could do two separate queries. One for the first 8 and then Union on another query which would get the remaining  result set.  I am just curious on how I would implement an iterator function to populate my wosequence column.

**TABLE**

```
wonum     parent     taskid     wosequence  
=====     ======     ======     ========
10        0          10
20        0          20       
30        0          30
..        ..         ..  

90        0          90   
100       0          100
```

**Desired Output**

```
wonum     parent     taskid     wosequence
=====     ======     ======     ========
10        0          10
20        0          20       
30        0          30
..        ..         ..  
                                    <------iterator would begin and insert its value
90        0          90         1
100       0          100        2
110       0          110        3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN ROW_NUMBER() > 7 
    THEN 
        ROW_NUMBER()-7 
    ELSE 
        '' 
END AS Wosequence
, colum2, column3 
FROM dbo.abc [..]
```

Comment: This solution works. I would like to add you have to add after the ROW_NUMBER() function to include OVER(BLAH BLAH).

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no row_number in mysql,  you could take that from a subquery and then perform the check:

```
SELECT
  wonum,
  parent,
  taskid,
  CASE
    WHEN Wosequence >=8
    THEN Wosequence
    FROM
      (
        SELECT
          wonum,
          parent,
          taskid,
          @row_number:=@row_number+1 AS Wosequence
        FROM
          table1,
          (
            SELECT
              @row_number:=0
          ) AS t
      )
```